# Regex "greedy" check

Tags: java

I'm trying to use a simple Regex to match a patttern but get some unexpected results...

The search pattern and results are given below,

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*xx");
        Matcher m = p.matcher("yyxxxyxx");
        while (m.find()){
            System.out.println("match start");
            System.out.println("Start = " + m.start());
            System.out.println("End = " + m.end());
            System.out.println("Group = " + m.group());

        }

    }
}
```

Result:

```
match start
Start = 0
End = 8
Group = yyxxxyxx
```

Expected Result:

```
match start
Start = 0
End = 4
Group = yyxx
match start
Start = 4
End = 8
Group = xyxx
```

Can someone explain how the regex operates ?

Answer (score 1):

As you've alluded to in your question title, the `*` here is greedy.  This means it will take as many characters as it can while still matching.  You just need to add `?` to make it lazy.

```
.*?xx
```

Answer (score 1):

Greedy means that it will go as far as possible before it decides that it has found the entire group.  Your regex basically says "Any number of characters terminated by 'xx'".  Since the entire string matches that description, you get the whole string as a group.

Perhaps you intended to use a lazy matcher instead of a greedy one?